# If frame is maximized?

Tags: frames

Is it possible (using only emacs-lisp) to find out if the current frame is maximized?

Not fullscreen, but maximized.

Comment: Here is one idea:  `(assq 'outer-size (frame-geometry))`; `(assq 'title-bar-size (frame-geometry))`; and `(assq 'tool-bar-size (frame-geometry))`.  See also:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Size.html

Comment: Did you try `(eq (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) 'maximized)`? See (elisp) [Size Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html).

Comment: @Drew sadly, this appears to be not working in OSX (Emacs 27 Cocoa), it just returns nil whether it's maximized or not

Comment: @Drew I stand corrected: I just re-installed latest from master and `(frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)` does return `'maximized`. Maybe it was broken and fixed recently, or something else. Would you please post this as an answer?

Comment: Although the call of the question seeks a pure `emacs-lisp` solution, here is a link to an `emacs-lisp` function that incorporates an applescript to get the bounds of the selected frame.  https://gist.github.com/d7000235c8510460079149ad25233f0d  Assuming the user knows the dimensions of what a maximized frame would be, that can be compared to the output of the `get-bounds` function.

Comment: Done - added it as an answer. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, as the test you want:

```
(eq (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) 'maximized)
```

See (elisp) [Size Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html).